# How do I solve prove this natural deduction problem?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Premises: $\neg(A \to B)\ ,\  \neg B \to C$ .

Conclusion: $C$

My intuition is that I should do a sub-derivation where I prove $\neg C$ is an absurdity. However, I soon run into issues. If I could prove that $B$ is an absurdity, that would work also, but I'm not sure how to do so using the first premise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after receiving five answer, the OP does not accept any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Start by assuming that B is true.

> You can prove a contradiction from that, to establish $\lnot B$.

> Within the assumption you can prove $A \to B$

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition is that I should do a sub-derivation where I prove $\neg C$ is an absurdity. However, I soon run into issues. If I could prove that $B$ is an absurdity, that would work also, but I'm not sure how to do so using the first premise.

The contradiction of the first premise requires but a conditional proof: derive $B$ under the assumption of $A$.

Since your instinct was to derive that contradiction under the assumption of $B$, go with that.

- $\neg(A\to B)$ by premise
- $\neg B\to C$ by premise

  - $\neg C$ by supposition

    - $B$ by supposition

      - $A$ by supposition
      - $B$ by reiteration
    - $A\to B$ by deduction (conditional introduction)
    - Contradiction!
  - $\neg B$ by denial (negation introduction)
  - $C$ by affirmation (modus ponens, or conditional elimination)
  - Contradiction!
- $\neg\neg C$ by denial
- $C$ by double negation elimination.

Which is a valid proof, but a little inspection reveals some redundancy which we may prune away.

- $\neg(A\to B)$ by premise
- $\neg B\to C$ by premise

  - $B$ by supposition

    - $A$ by supposition
    - $B$ by reiteration
  - $A\to B$ by deduction (conditional introduction)
  - Contradiction!
- $\neg B$ by denial (negation introduction)
- $C$ by affirmation (modus ponens, or conditional elimination)

Answer (score 0):

Write the first premise as $\neg\neg(A \land \neg B) \equiv A \land \neg B $ , so $\neg B$ is true. Therefore, from the second premise it follows $C$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to assume $¬C$, here is an intuitionistic derivation:

$1). ¬(A → B) - premise$

$2). (¬B → C) - premise$

$3). B - assumption$

$4). A - assumption$

$5). A → B - I→ in 3,4 $

$6). ⊥ in  1,5$

$7). B - EFSQ (close-assumption- 5)$

$8). A → B - I→ in 4,7$

$9). ⊥ in 1,8  (close-assumption-4)$

$10). ¬B - I¬ in 3$

$11). C - E→ in 2,10$

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: You can simplify it. You have $A \to B$, and thus a contradiction with 1). Now derive directly 10) $\lnot B$ by $(\lnot \text I)$, discharging the assumption, and use it to derive $C$.

Comment: How do I discharge assumption 4? Can I make a derivation with only the assumption B?

Comment: The *conditional introduction* at 5 discharges the assumption of $A$.  Usually you would reiterate $B$ so it is *explicitly* stated in the context of the assumption; but as it is *implicitly* available, it is technically okay. (See my answer for clarification). However, this subproof is also so trivial that *some* systems do allow you to *immediately* infer $A\to B$ from $B$ as a secondary conditional introduction (which is what you may have been thinking about).

Comment: Of course, it was so simple that I did not realize it even in Mauro's explanation. I remember now that the way we express (p ⇒ (q ⇒ p)) in natural deduction is through the repetition rule. Thank you¡¡

Answer (score 0):

$A \Rightarrow B$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg A) \vee B$.

**Start of Edit Insert**
See lemontree's comments/reactions to my answer which seem to indicate that the above statement can not be assumed, but rather must be proven.  Based on this indication, I agree with lemontree that this answer is both unintended and inferior to other answers presented. 
**End of Edit Insert**

Consequently, its negation is $A \wedge (\neg B).$

So you are given that

$A \wedge (\neg B)$

and

$(\neg B) \Rightarrow C.$

Comment: Deriving these equivalences in ND is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @lemontree Although I am unfamiliar with the phrase ND, it seems like you have a good point.  I would question however, whether the 1st statement in my answer needs derivation, or if it can be regards as immediately true.  I really can't answer that.  I do think that if it is **not** allowed to assume that it is true, then my approach is not a good one.

Comment: The question is about how to prove the inference in natural deduction (= ND).